# Displaying 8 bit grayscale bitmap in MFC

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, bitmap, mfc

I am creating an app where display is handled by MFC & Image processing is handled by OpenCV. For the first part, I load a 24 bpp bitmap (color) from Memory using CImage->Load(), display it using StretchBlt() & then hand over hand over pointer to raw data using CImage's GetBits() function to OpenCV Mat. This half works great as I can display orig. color image in my MFC app & can subsequently strip the color image into various grayscale formats(r, G, B Sobel) using OpenCV.(verified using Opencv-> imshow()

```
CImage myImage;
wchar_t* wcharPointer=(_T("C:\\TestPic.bmp"));
myImage.Load(wcharPointer);
myImage.StretchBlt(dc.m_hDC,0,0,
                     myImage.GetWidth(),myImage.GetHeight(),SRCCOPY);

Mat m1(294,456,CV_8UC3,((unsigned char*)myImage.GetBits())-(293*456*3));    
//-(293*456*3) Because bitmap is Bottom up,still, image displayed is     
 //inverted 
Mat  arrayOf3[3];
split(m1,arrayOf3);
```

Now when I want to pass pointer to an 8bit grayscale image back to MFC to display in the app, I seem to be running into issues. Since CImage decalres m_pBits as prvate, I cant just assign cv::Mat ->data to CImage.

Approach 1 was as follows

```
CBitmap bitmap1;CDC memdc;
memdc.CreateCompatibleDC( &dc);
bitmap1.CreateBitmap(456,294,1,8,(void*)arrayOf3[0].data);
```

//This returns 1, so I assume successfull handoff from OpenCV to MFC?

dc.BitBlt(10,0,456,294,&memdc,0,0,SRCCOPY); //But this results in blank screen
   // Approach 1 fails..Not exactly sure why..Maybe DDB not DIB is created

So Onto Approach2, I create a bitmapInfo & populate with all requisite values.

```
BITMAPINFO bitInfo={0};
    memset(&bitInfo, 0, sizeof(bitInfo));
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSize        =   sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth       =   456;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight      =   -294; // top-down image 
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes      =   1;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount    =   8;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression =   BI_RGB; //Uncompressed image
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage   =   456*294;
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed     =   0;   
    bitInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant=   0;
```

I looked around & my understanding of how to populate the color table in this case is lacking.
1 approach I saw involved up scaling each 8 bit grayscale image to 24 bpp(or 32) in the color table, which I would like to avoid, since this operation is time sensitive.
How should I generate my Colortable? Also, how should I proceed after that?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: "How should I generate my Colortable?" -- do you mean how to generate a grayscale palette? A simple loop from 0 to 255 (inclusive) setting all three colour components to the same value.

Comment: Something like this? <br/> for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
   bitInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbRed   = *(unsigned char*) arrayOf3[0].data);
   bitInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = *(unsigned char*) arrayOf3[0].data);
   bitInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbBlue  =*(unsigned char*) arrayOf3[0].data);
  }

Comment: Not exactly. The pixels in your single channel image are bytes, that can have value from 0 (lowest intensity) to 255 (highest intensity). The palette provides a mapping between those values and RGB colors. Let's say you want to display it as shades of gray. In that case value of 0 will map to (0,0,0), value of 127 will map to (127,127,127) and 255 will map to (255,255,255). In this case, you'd assign the value of `i` to each of the R, G, and B components of palette entry `i`.

Comment: Not familiar with OpenCV, but, can you use [AfxDrawGrayBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ka8zyd.aspx)?

Comment: Setting `biBitCount` to 8 implies, that you are using an indexed image (one where a color table immediately following the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure). This means, that you must provide a palette. As an aside, your calculation for `biSizeImage` is wrong. It needs to take the stride into account, which may or may not be the same as the width. For `BI_RGB` it's best to just leave it at 0, and have the system deal with it.

Comment: @ItsTheJourney if you were able to solve the issue, could you please share the solution. I also want to display 8bit opencv img in a MFC dialog window but am unable to.